# "Smart Quotes" not displaying properly in email from phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, smart-quotes

I'm dealing with a LAMP web server. I have forms that users use to submit text that is stored in a text field in mysql. Often this text is copied and pasted from Microsoft Office products, so I'm getting a lot of smart quotes and emdashes. These characters display properly if I retrieve them from the database and display them on the webpage, but where I'm running into trouble is sending the text in an email using the phpmailer class. I get stuff that looks like this: â€“ (where it should be an emdash).

One thing that *may* be important: If I pull up a console in mysql and select a field that has an emdash or smart quote in it, it will display on my console incorrectly: â€“, however, as stated above, if my php page (using PDO) selects the field and displays it, it will display correctly in a browser (as an emdash in this case).

I'm not sure if there's a way to select a character set in phpmailer, (maybe it's a simple setting somewhere?) or if there is a better way around this problem. I think I should be clear, though, that "search and replace smart quotes and emdashes with their regular equivalents" is NOT the answer I'm looking for (hopefully that's not the only solution).

I found this information:
My php webpage: utf-8
mysql client encoding: latin1
mysql server encoding: latin1
phpmailer character set: iso-8859-1

Comment: You should remove them and replace them with legitimate characters.

Comment: Fancy quotes and the like are of the devil. Publishing ISO-8859-* (or rather, everything but ASCII and Unicode) encoded stuff on the web in general is.

Comment: why can't the character encodings be used?

Comment: what is encodings of all involved matters (webpage, database, email)?

Comment: Why aren't smart quotes "legitimate"?

Comment: So, make your phpmailer charset utf-8

Comment: @delnan: â€“ is clearly a sign that something is trying to use Unicode (UTF-8 in particular). @ctb: You need to set your phpmailer character set to utf-8. I'd post this as an answer, except I don't know how to set that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Character set can be switched in phpmailer with the following code:

```
$myMail->CharSet  = "UTF-8";
```

This solved my issue. Typographic quotes and double dashes show up in my emails from phpmailer as expected now. This may have been a sorta noobish question (blush). Thanks, Col. Shrapnel for prompting me to look into what encoding all the pieces of the puzzle were using. I'd vote you up but don't have the reputation.

For anyone interested in homework, this link really helped me understand the basics of encoding:
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

The PEAR Mail_MIME package lets you do this via http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.get.php  I am pretty certain I have used this feature before, but not positive.

You may also need to run things through [iconv](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to normalize the character sets to a single one, if there are multiple data sources.